# Photoshop: Close All without prompting? (CS3/CS4)

Tags: adobe-photoshop

While editing a lot of source images and saving them for web, I eventually want to close all of the original images without saving them.

How can I CLOSE ALL without Photoshop prompting me if I want to save changes to each file?

Answer (score 4):

In newer versions (I'm using CC):

File->Close All, then tick the box in the pop up dialogue to apply your selected save selection to all documents.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Photoshop scripting feature described here: [www.photoshopsupport.com](http://www.photoshopsupport.com/tutorials/jennifer/photoshop-scripts.html)

As for your questen there is a script here that might be useful for you: http://morris-photographics.com/photoshop/scripts/close-without-save.html

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't appear to be an option for this, however you can click close all (or hold the shift key down and click one of the X's on the tab) and then hit `D` to close the dialog without saving.

Answer (score 0):

You can also close a bunch of documents while recording an Action, and the option you clicked on the dialogs will be saved in the Action.   So you can record an Action that consists of five Close without saving commands, for example, and assign it to a hotkey. Pretty simple compared to the scripting option.

(Note that the Close All menu command itself doesn't get recorded. You can choose "Insert Menu Item" from the Actions palette but then on playback you are faced with the same problem - the confirmation dialog pops up.)